# OOP Coventions. Object Array

Tags: oop, standards

I have been coding for a year but I've only been introduced and taught in lesson about OOP recently.

I posted a question earlier and somebody said that my program would be a lot better off using a player Class

I was wondering if it is of standard convention to use an object array?

So I need 10 players in my program. Is it okay to have an array of the Class Player with 10 instances? Or is this bad?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you plan on using the objects. There is certainly no problem at all creating a  array of 10 Player objects. Another option, which may or may not be relevant to your program, could be to create an additional class that contains this array of 10 player instances (maybe call it "Team"?). This would make sense if you want to define methods or members that relate to the 10 players, such as wins/losses, or something of that nature.

Comment: I have a question. 

 My game will have a Super Class called player. I'm wondering if this needs to have some derived class' from it.

 The user can create 10 players. He can pick between Dwarf, Humand, or Gnome.

 The only difference between the 3 is their starting health. All the functions are the same. 

 Would i need to create 3 more class which inherit Player class for Dwarf, Human, Gnome which have different values for their starting health?

Or would i just say "if dwarf then Player[1].health = 50" ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If the only difference between the races is health, then you could simply modify the health of the player object. However, if you want to leave room for expansion you should make each race it's own class and that extends the Player class. You could then have the class's constructors set their max health accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would be a perfectly valid (and very common) usage.